# I want to extract data from a string

Tags: php

I have a string like the one below. I want to be able to extract the data and put it into variables. I would have used a function that focuses on a specifically formatted string but then it would create problems if the string is slightly different.

```
$str ="Surname : Lorem Creme
       Name : Doe 
       Bank name :P.O.S
       Account no:50345343
       EC no:0000000K
       ID no :85-000000 Q 85
       DOB : 01-06-34
       Employer name:min of education
       Employeer Number: Borera pry 066 Mutawatawa
       Client Physical Address: 45 New Lipore";

function ge($string, $start, $end){
     $string = ' '. $string;
     $ini =strpos($string, $start);
     if ($ini == 0) return '';
     $ini += strlen($start);
     $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
     $den =substr($string, $ini, $len);
     return substr($den, 0, -4);

 }

if (isset($_POST['insert'])){
     $real = $str;
$guru = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $real);
$rem = str_replace(':', '', $guru);
$ren = str_replace('-', '', $rem);
$surname = ge($ren, "Surname", "Name");


$firstname =ge($ren, "Name", "Bankname");
$account_number = ge($ren, "Accountno", "ECno");
$Ec = ge($ren, "ECno", "IDno");
$id_num = ge($ren, 'IDno', "DOB");
$dob = ge($ren, "DOB", "Employername");
// Employer name:min of education
echo "First name: $firstname <br> Last name: $surname <br>";
echo "Bank : $bank_name <br>";
echo "ID Number : $id_num <br>";
echo "Account Number : $account_number <br>";
echo "DOB : $dob <br>";
echo "EC Number : $nex_ofk";
}
```

`

Comment: `explode()` is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: I want to post the data to an sql database so for example the surname should be stored in a $surname variable, name in the name variable and so on

Comment: explode by new line then explode by ":"

Comment: I have been trying to use explode() but it seems as if I am missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use php `explode()` function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

First do explode by new row to get rows (check on PHP_EOL constant here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) and loop through them.

Then use another `explode()` call to explode by ":" sign to get field name and field value.

Use `trim()` function to remove space characters if they bother you.

```
$rows = explode(PHP_EOL, $str);
foreach ($rows as $row){
  $rowParts = explode(':', $row);
  $fieldName = trim($rowParts[0]);
  $fieldValue = trim($rowParts[1]);
}
```

Should be something like that (I didn't test the code).

Comment: It would be far more productive to show the OP some code rather than just links to manual pages.

Comment: This extracts the data into `$fieldName` and `$fieldValue`, but then does nothing with it.

Comment: That was the question - how to extract data. Not to do anything with it.

Answer (score 3):

You can either you explode() twice with new line and then with `:` or you simple regex with preg_match_all

```
$str ="Surname : Lorem Creme
       Name : Doe 
       Bank name :P.O.S
       Account no:50345343
       EC no:0000000K
       ID no :85-000000 Q 85
       DOB : 01-06-34
       Employer name:min of education
       Employeer Number: Borera pry 066 Mutawatawa
       Client Physical Address: 45 New Lipore";


preg_match_all("#^\s*(.*?):\s*(.*?)\s*$#mx", $str, $matches);

var_dump(array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]));
```

**Output:**

```
array(10) {
  ["Surname "]=>
  string(11) "Lorem Creme"
  ["Name "]=>
  string(3) "Doe"
  ["Bank name "]=>
  string(5) "P.O.S"
  ["Account no"]=>
  string(8) "50345343"
  ["EC no"]=>
  string(8) "0000000K"
  ["ID no "]=>
  string(14) "85-000000 Q 85"
  ["DOB "]=>
  string(8) "01-06-34"
  ["Employer name"]=>
  string(16) "min of education"
  ["Employeer Number"]=>
  string(25) "Borera pry 066 Mutawatawa"
  ["Client Physical Address"]=>
  string(13) "45 New Lipore"
}
```

The magic is in regex `#^\s*(.*?):\s*(.*?)\s*$#mx` you can find explanation [here](https://regex101.com/r/7puSsN/1)

`array_combine()` gets the values from 2 groups and combine them together to get one array. 
`preg_match_all` applies regex to given string and return the output in 
 `$matches` array

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is with two `explode` calls:

```
<?php
$str ="Surname : Lorem Creme
       Name : Doe 
       Bank name :P.O.S
       Account no:50345343
       EC no:0000000K
       ID no :85-000000 Q 85
       DOB : 01-06-34
       Employer name:min of education
       Employeer Number: Borera pry 066 Mutawatawa
       Client Physical Address: 45 New Lipore";


//Split string into separate lines
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $str);

$result = array();
foreach($lines as $ln){
    //Use explode to get the pieces left and right of the ':'
    list($key, $val) = explode(':', $ln);

    //Put that in a new array; use trim to get rid of 'presumably' unwanted whitespace
    $result[trim($key)] = trim($val);
}

var_dump($result);


?>
```

You can also do this in one line with a regular expression, but this is probably simpler to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your delimiter is, you can use explode()

In this case it looks like your delimiter is "\r\n". The explode would look like this:

```
$result = explode("\r\n", $str);
```

Afterwards you can explode on ":" as well, to get at key value result